# xcode/ios/json api: Is it best practice to use pagination when pulling in json feed?

Tags: ios, json, xcode, pagination

IOS newb working on app that pulls JSON feed from web server into an IOS app.

Is it best practice to create an API (in PHP in my case) that spills all the records--which could be thousands into a JSON feed and have the IOS app handle all of them (though displaying only one screen at a time)?

Or is best practice to limit the results in the JSON feed to say ten or one hundred and then have some user action in the IOS App draw down the next batch?

The first would seem more desirable given the reusable cell concept, however, it seems that sending huge numbers of records is bound to be slower and/or problematic from a web traffic and memory management point of view.

On the other hand, the second seems really complicated.  How would you know which page to pull down based on IOS style gestures.

Looking to learn best practice on this as it seems to be common for many apps.

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably depends on your use case. If you have **a lot** of data then you probably wouldn't want to load all of them at once. At a certain point it will take too much time and you probably have to do that more than once if you don't persist or if you want to refresh.

In that case a good API is designed to be iterated over e.g. limit/offset parameters. Meaning for example the user scrolls a list of items and when scrolling to the bottom of the list you fetch a new batch of items.

In the other case where one call is fast enough to deliver all the data at once there is no reason to make it more complicated as you said and you can still add iteration afterwards.

Comment: For case 2, can you recommend tutorial or code where it shows how to load next batch in conjunction with api?  I guess you would have to specify  parameter for next 10 or whatever in response to an upward scroll touch or something but it seems hard.

Comment: No, it's actually not hard. You can catch the scroll position on the device and add a dynamic parameter to page through the data. You may wanna take a look at this project: https://github.com/nmondollot/NMPaginator